# Double labeling of figures, tables, etc

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing, templates

I'm using the following template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/win-template-thesis-latex/ngwnxbshbdnn

And I countinously get that my figures and tables have a double reference, by which I mean, I continously get the following:
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

I have no clue how to fix it. Can anyone help?

I've used this code:

```
    \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/FCNDP.png}
       \caption{An example of a FCNDP solution}
       \label{fig:fcndp}
    \end{figure}
```

and I'm not entirely sure where else to seek for how this template was build.

Comment: Instead of linking to a template, please show the code that you have used.

Comment: @daleif i just used the general \begin{figure} ... \end{figure} that you get automatically. Or do you have any advice on where to seek?

Comment: Please provide a minimal code *here*. External links are discouraged because your question will become meaningless when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ). (And there are people like me without overleaf account...)

Comment: I have! But i cant imagine it being usefull.

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting errors about undefined `\figure@caption`? It looks like the class redefines `figure` to expect a key/val list.

Comment: I tracked the template [here](https://www.is.rw.fau.eu/teaching/theses/guidelines-theses/) and added the code from the question to it. It worked as expected, so maybe the issue is related to overleaf?

Answer (score 1):

The class file expects you to specify the caption using an "optional" keyword argument for the `figure` environment, as shown line 46 of the original template (below). The class file redefines the `figure` environment to automatically add a (possibly empty) `\caption` using this argument, resulting in the double "**Figure X**". So, you should use the syntax below, rather than adding your own `\caption`.

```
\begin{figure}[label={fig:img01}, caption={Relationship of students and theses}]
  ...
\end{figure}
```

Aside: IMO, whoever designed this class incorporated too much of their personal preferences for syntax, resulting in unexpected behaviour like this, and likely incompatibilities with packages you may want to use.